# Apache Hive regex returns all NULL values

Tags: regex, apache, hive

I am using apache Hive 0.11 with the regex serde but when I do a select (*) from table limit 5 every column has NULL as value when there should be data.

My create script:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE log_corelio (timestamp STRING, ad STRING, cookieID STRING, slot STRING, language STRING, randomNumber STRING, age STRING, gender STRING, city STRING, date STRING, interests STRING, brands STRING, country STRING, region STRING, pageview_count STRING, member_status STRING, isp STRING, screen_width STRING, hashkey STRING, id STRING, ag STRING, ge STRING, l1 STRING, l2 STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "^\[([^\]]*)\]\|\/pool\/([^|]*)\|([^\|]*)\|GET \/ad\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)","output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s %11$s %12$s %13$s %14$s %15$s %16$s %17$s %18$s %19$s %20$s %21$s %22$s %23$s %24$s")
LOCATION '/user/adhese/corelio/corelio6';
```

Regex only:

```
^\[([^\]]*)\]\|\/pool\/([^|]*)\|([^\|]*)\|GET \/ad\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)
```

I don't really see what is wrong, I expect I need to escape something in my regex but I don't know what.

Regex should match:

```
[21/May/2013:23:59:59 +0100]|/pool/256955.log|62.235.161.115.1369169828196156|GET /ad/32869/nl/147/_age_/_gender_/_city_/_date_/;adttr12842;adttrlifestyle;adttrwielrennen;gmbl;prx/Explorer;Explorer9;Scarlet;Windows7;screen3/BE/01/21/undefined/Scarlet/_screenWidth_/_hashKey_/_ID_/_AG_/_GE_/_l1_/_l2_/|200|2|987||||
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

darkownage : " i tested your regex - the log record failed to match with the regex" . The record should **match completely** with the regex then only RegexserDe works. note completely

Test tool : [regex rubular](http://rubular.com/) -- please check the last part of the regex & record last lines having some empty pipes(this part was unmatched -- /|200|2|987||||)

**reason for NULL :**

Refer the [RegexSerDe](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/trunk/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/RegexSerDe.java) documentation comments.

main points:

- In deserialization stage, `if a row does not match the regex, then all columns in the row will be NULL`. If a row matches the regex but has less than expected groups, the missing groups will be NULL. If a row matches the regex but has more than expected groups, the additional groups are just ignored

Comment: Missed that part in the documentation :) In my eyes the last part was useless so I thought I didn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You should test using `\\` instead of only 1 `\`. I found that `\w` did not match my regex but when I wrote `\\w` it worked perfectly.

Comment: What is the difference between the first `"\w"` and the second `"\w"`?